# Memory management in bruteforcing

Tags: python, python-3.x, authentication, memory, brute-force

Intro:

I've been writing a python script to brute-force a login page.
I am trying to see if the username exists on the database first.
I've passed a wordlist to my script, there are permutations and combinations from which the program attempts to login.

Problem:

My computer hangs after a certain time i think the memory gives in. How do i flush memory with a conditional statement. Like if the username doesnt exists just flush the memory and move to the next combination or permutation.

My naive Code (incomplete):

```
import sys
from itertools import permutations
import inspect
import requests as req



symbols = '''01234567890_;.:=!@#$^*-'''
symbols = list(symbols)


crack = "User_name" 

with open(sys.argv[1]) as wordlist:
    words = wordlist.readlines()
    words = [x.replace("\n", "") for x in words]
    perm = permutations(words, 2)
    

        
for i in list(perm):
    for x in i:
        for y in range(len(i)):
            if x != i[y]:
                for j in symbols:
                    print(x + j + i[y])
                    print(x + i[y] + j)
                    if x + j + i[y] == crack:
                        found = crack
                    if x + i[y] + j == crack:
                        found = crack
                #print(x + i[y])
                found = crack
```

Comment: Please supply the expected [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") . We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points. This allows testing suggestions against your data and desired output.

Comment: So you essentially need the word list? Cause everything else is stated in the code you can run it

Comment: at least a sample of the word list would be helpful, it doesn't have to be the full list, say the first 5 to 10 items.

Comment: john /n, smith /n, todd /n, jennifer /n , love /n, 123 /n etc you get the idea